# Receiving wrong status code in HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm using WebApi for my service. It has a controller with a GET method. When I call it from the client and return Unauthorized status code, I don't get Unauthorized in the HttpResponseMessage, but NotFound instead.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/dummies")]
public class DummiesController : ApiController
{    
  [Route("test")]
  [HttpGet]
  public IHttpActionResult GetTest()
  {
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
  }
}
```

This is how I call it from client:

```
public class Persistance
{
  private HttpClient _client;

  public Persistance()
  {
    _client = new HttpClient();
    _client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:10767/");
  }

  public async Task DummyMethod()
  {
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync("api/dummies/test");
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
      // etc..
    }
  }
}
```

The content of the `response`:

```
StatusCode  NotFound    System.Net.HttpStatusCode
```

I put a breakpoint at the GetTest() and it stops there, so it reaches the controller method.

Why do I get NotFound, instead of Unauthorized in the client?

Comment: you specify invalid uri. enter full path: GetAsync("http:// localhost....")

Comment: I set the Uri in the constructor. Added the code of the constructor.

Comment: your controller looks fine. i create test webapi application and able to call api/dummies/test in browser (was response).

Comment: also i created console application with Persistance class. StatusCode in DummyMethod was Unauthorized. all done in visual studio 2015 update 3.

Answer (score -1):

Controller route attribute `[Route("api/[controller]")]` is there?

or

delete action route and you can try this

```
[HttpGet("test")]
```

Comment: Yes, the controller attribute is there. See my edits. I get `error CS1729: 'System.Web.Http.HttpGetAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments`, if I use your suggestion.

Comment: sorry my fault. my code using with netcore. Did you check HttpGet library? if it System.Web.Mvc then you get this problem? So I try your code and get unauthorized response.

Comment: I don't use Mvc, it's WebApi. What do you mean by checking the HttpGet library?